# Type guards not detecting cloned objects

Tags: typescript

Why does type guard work for the object itself, but not for the clones of that object? Here is my code ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEAmqC8cDeAsAFBxlyYCGMlAXOlsACLWUDcJ5cAlpvQM4wo3AHYBzDsQC+k0JFgJkqDNhY04eIqXIAbSgCNgOgPwChoiZ3IBjABbcdmKMBH0VzVgGF7j5yMkyJCRIKAyqXj5OLhpWZAA+BLFc5CHA9ACiINY6AK7YADzuapTeDpgAKkoANGEeNKWOlSgAdJ4AEgDyAJKe6QDKAHySyXBSSQlaI1ypbozFDRVKrZ09-cNTZHYQ3NbA-KZwAIJQUJSIhXMRZd7bu0NJZIHEJHLQ8C45ALa185FNqJNyO1ur0+ho4AAiLY7PYQqpJcrpAAa5XBEJgoBgcKSng6aHKXTQAFV0mjrBARDBRDlgNjtGQ0HjSXgISIKbT4dIXuA3opQkUro4bjDwYCyLwzMJxAFJCRsNlKM44DpgPA2dhZthJPK9EqVWrGF0+HBBFLLM9iNwAGZwAAU6uAzSoNGadjKfmaqQ0ODwAvqfyWwNWYIAZCG4A7mrxvXgHUaAJSJelwckiQQR4AAd3corgzXzDtG602FP4EBVzR0EDE9qz7idrFdkQ90N2-BqkedlCb7pcTdue3jASAA)):

```
if (
  node.data.children.type === NodeDataChildType.CHOICES &&
  node.id === nodeId
) {
  const newNode = { ...node };
  console.log(
    newNode.data.children.choices, // cloned object, giving error
    node.data.children.choices // original object, no errors
  );
}
```

(Please note: I know both `choices` above are the same array since object spread just does a shallow clone. I'm logging both of them to demonstrate the type error on the cloned object.)

I'm getting this error:

```
Property 'choices' does not exist on type 'NodeDataChildren'.
  Property 'choices' does not exist on type '{ type: NodeDataChildType.TEXT | NodeDataChildType.CONTINUE | NodeDataChildType.NONE; }'.ts(2339)
```

[image]
[image]

Here are the types:

```
export type Node = {
data: NodeData
id: string;
}
export type NodeData = {
  label?: string;
  children: NodeDataChildren;
};

type NodeDataChildren =
  | {
      type: Exclude<NodeDataChildType, NodeDataChildType.CHOICES>;
    }
  | {
      type: NodeDataChildType.CHOICES;
      choices?: Array<NodeDataChildChoice>;
    };

export enum NodeDataChildType {
  CHOICES = "choices",
  TEXT = "text",
  CONTINUE = "continue",
  NONE = "none",
}
export type NodeDataChildChoice = {
  id: string;
};
```

**Note: This is not built in Node type, but a custom Node Type**

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've just added it , please check

Comment: Okay, I'll link that shortly

Comment: Note that your `console.log` is logging the **exact same array** twice. `{ ...node }` only does a shallow copy, not a deep one. Both `node` and `newNode` share the `data` object (and thus its `children` object, and *its* `choices` array). [Here's how to do a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) if you need one.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. Both objects reference the same array, yet typescript throws the error when accessing it from a shallow copy object.

Comment: I'm just saying: Why log the same object twice? But if it's just to show the error, that's fair enough. :-) (FWIW: Here's a version using a deep copy without the type error: https://tsplay.dev/mx3BGN, because the type of `children` is narrowed directly.)

Comment: Yes, that is for demonstrating the error :D, I haven't written the logic yet. Thank you for being patient and understanding my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just hitting one of the many limits of automatic type narrowing. I think the primary problem is that your code is narrowing the type of `node.data.children`, but then just copying `node`. Since `node`'s type hasn't been narrowed by a type guard, `newNode` just gets the plain `Node` type — and that type has a union for `data.children`. **You** know (and we know) that `node` and `newNode` share the same `data` object, and thus the same `data.children` object, but TypeScript doesn't go that far.

When I run into a limit like that, I like to use a type assertion function, for example:

```typescript
function assertIsChoicesNodeData(children: NodeDataChildren): asserts children is NodeDataChildrenWithChoices {
    if ((children as any).type !== NodeDataChildType.CHOICES) {
        throw new Error("Expected a children object with `type` = `NodeDataChildType.CHOICES`");
    }
}
```

Type assertions are a Bad Thing™ most of the time, but a type assertion *function* is a different beast because it doesn't just trust the programmer, it *verifies* the assertion at runtime.

Here's how you'd use it:

```typescript
if (node.data.children.type === NodeDataChildType.CHOICES && node.id === nodeId) {
    const newNode = { ...node };
    assertIsChoicesNodeData(newNode.data.children);
    console.log(node.data.children.choices, newNode.data.children.choices);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEAmqC8cDeAsAFBxlyYCGMlAXOlsACLWUDcJ5cAlpvQM4wo3AHYBzDsQC+k0JFgJkqDNhY04eIqXIAbSgCNgOgPwChoiZ3IBjABbcdmKMBH0VzVgGF7j5yMkyJCRIKAyqXj5OLgDq3DC23hDc1sD8GgRwAPSZcABU+XAACgCuOjrAmAj2aRDF8BAAZlWoxSLcECJwlGlxNQDunSGolDrc3VZkQ26MapTeDpgAKkoAdJ4AEgDyAJKeAKIAypJcdkkp-KZwAIJQUJSIADzus-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-zU7BC3Au8yAtERBHgvp3BDOAVis-NKXYshK3yXI4HWBtgFxfJEFqAoAGtXTg+JqEo-MaMoERKgokQEPcGj+FsBNUHiVB+EoHlUAooTKBo-CiLbMFK1Cyp4mKNJEuLFK0oykSXxcCiVjgAAhOoujAMB4pEGAdEQOBCQOaxhDAFNgAqNJKDgex2pWMF9xnOdmTlRd+Ki9TKtEkQ2LBIz+AgcoVh0CAxH45bWCqrcRCqll+FxSKzKO4TVvOuV1q4oA)

Comment: It works! I also got to learn some new stuff. Thank you for your time

Comment: @omar - No worries. I have a nagging feeling there's a better answer out there, though... :-)

Comment: There is a way to avoid this (though looks really powerful), that is by declaring a variable before the if statement and type guard that variable instead of the original object. It will though create a new object on every iteration though.

```
  const newNode = { ...node };

        if (
          newNode.data.children.type === NodeDataChildType.CHOICES &&
          node.id === nodeId
        )
```

Comment: Well, yes, you can always do that. :-)